# Function triggered multiple times in a TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

The function that play sound when i answer the call is trigerred multiple times not only once.
I have tryed to add a check to avoid but doesnt work it continue to start sound with the function playNext.
The sound is played multiple times.

```
 public class tuneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
boolean check = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // If state has changed
    if ((intent != null) && intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)) {
            String extraData = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (extraData.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "RINGING" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if (extraData.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "OFFHOOK" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (check) {
                        playNext(context);
                    }
            }
            else if (extraData.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    // CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "IDLE" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    check = true;




            }
        }
    }
}

private void playNext(Context context) {

    check = false;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String randomurl = prefs.getString("randomurl", "no id"); //no id: default value
    final Uri myUri = Uri.parse(randomurl);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, myUri);
    mp.start();

}


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the thing was that i declare 2 times the broadcast receiver.
In manifest and programattically.
Removed the one from manifest solve the problem

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                         final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new EarntunesReceiver();
                                         final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
                                         getApplication().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                                     } else {

                                     }




<receiver android:name=".ReceiverCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```